# BASH: Convert multi lined (JSON) block into a single line string

Tags: json, bash

I have below JSON output written into "out" file and the content is as below.

$ cat out

```
{
    "columns": [
        "Tests",
        "Errors",
        "Mean Test Time (ms)",
        "Test Time Standard Deviation (ms)",
        "TPS",
        "Peak TPS"
    ],
    "status": {
        "description": "Collection stopped",
        "state": "Stopped"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "description": "Cheetah client test",
            "statistics": [
                0,
                0,
                "NaN",
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0
            ],
            "test": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "Reads 95%",
            "statistics": [
                304000,
                0,
                8.7931875,
                7.948696618436826,
                6907.677974959667,
                13594.0
            ],
            "test": 101
        },
        {
            "description": "Writes 5%",
            "statistics": [
                16000,
                0,
                9.963375,
                9.92775949594747,
                363.5619986820878,
                1638.0
            ],
            "test": 102
        }
    ],
    "totals": [
        320000,
        0,
        8.851696875,
        8.063234652303947,
        7271.239973641756,
        14259.0
    ]
}
```

I need stats pertaining to the block of description "reads 95%" arrange in below format and assign to a string variable using a BASH script.

```
var=304000,0,8.7931875,7.948696618436826,6907.677974959667,13594.0
```

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using a dedicated command line JSON parser for this e.g. [underscore](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli):

With underscore installed you can do:

```
cat data.json | underscore select '.description, .statistics first-child'| tr -d '[]'
```

**EDIT:** Sed only solution (use it with caution):

```
sed -rn '/"description": *"Reads 95%",/,/],/{/statistics|description/!{1h; 1!H;};/],/{x;s/ *\n *|^ *|],//gp;};}' out

# gives 304000,0,8.7931875,7.948696618436826,6907.677974959667,13594.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. BTW i'm ok to arrange the output as below using bash.
304000,0,8.7931875,7.948696618436826,6907.677974959667,13594.0

Comment: Using underscore you can simple do: `cat data.json | underscore extract 'statistics'` for that

Comment: It can be done using pure bash tools also but let me tell you that its going to break it sooner than later.

Comment: To be more precise, I got this block after manipulating below two steps.
step 1: curl -s -X GET http://localhost:6373/recording/data | python -mjson.tool > out

step 2: sed -nr 'H;/Reads 95%/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}' out

Note: out consist many blocks like the block I have presented in the quesition

Your solution sounds for a json file, to my understanding. appreciate your guidance and support

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support.    

I got the intended result from below.   

sed -nr "H;/$name/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}" out | sed -e '1,/statistics/d' | sed -e '/test/,$d' | sed '$d' | sed '/^$/d' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | tr "\\n" " " | sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d'

Comment: You're using multiple commands to achieve something that showed how to get in 1 single sed command.

Comment: Can you please share that? so that I can accept as the answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: Sorry, I have not shared the results before. Below is what I'm getting, 3 lined output (each line separated with # symbols) . I have used "out" (please refer my answer) instead data.json

---------------------


0, 0, "NaN", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ### 
0, 0, "NaN", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 304000, 0, 8.7931875, 7.948696618436826, 6907.677974959667, 13594.0 ### 
0, 0, "NaN", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 304000, 0, 8.7931875, 7.948696618436826, 6907.677974959667, 13594.0 16000, 0, 9.963375, 9.92775949594747, 363.5619986820878, 1638.0

Comment: I edited the answer again. Try now. It now prints all 3 matches of description in 1 line. It is not what you expect provide your **expected output** in your question (not in comments) and use proper indentation of SO to make it readable.

Comment: I need specific statistics pertaining to the description "Reads 95%"

Comment: As I suggested provide your expected output for file out in your question (not in comments) and use proper indentation of SO to make it readable.

Comment: Superb! it's working nicely. Many thanks to you for the continuous support.

Answer (score 0):

My "pure shell" solution is below

```
cat data.json | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | awk  -F ': *' 'BEGIN { RS=",\n\"|\n}," } { gsub(/[\n\]\[\}]/,"",$2); if ($2) { printf("%s,", $2); } }'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I have tried your solution and it gives all in a single row and comma delimitted. However this required further manipulation to extract the intended portion out of it

Comment: Useless use of `cat` spotted!

Answer (score 0):

The out file contains Grinder (an open source load testing tool) test data parsed to JSON

```
curl -s -X GET http://<localhost>:6373/recording/data' | python -mjson.tool > out

~$ cat out

{
    "columns": [
        "Tests",
        "Errors",
        "Mean Test Time (ms)",
        "Test Time Standard Deviation (ms)",
        "TPS",
        "Peak TPS"
    ],
    "status": {
        "description": "Collection stopped",
        "state": "Stopped"
    },
    "tests": [
        {
            "description": "Cheetah client test",
            "statistics": [
                0,
                0,
                "NaN",
                0.0,
                0.0,
                0.0
            ],
            "test": 1
        },
        {
            "description": "Reads 95%",
            "statistics": [
                304000,
                0,
                8.7931875,
                7.948696618436826,
                6907.677974959667,
                13594.0
            ],
            "test": 101
        },
        {
            "description": "Writes 5%",
            "statistics": [
                16000,
                0,
                9.963375,
                9.92775949594747,
                363.5619986820878,
                1638.0
            ],
            "test": 102
        }
    ],
    "totals": [
        320000,
        0,
        8.851696875,
        8.063234652303947,
        7271.239973641756,
        14259.0
    ]
}
```

Sed command:

```
sed -nr "H;/$name/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}" out | sed -e     '1,/statistics/d' | sed -e '/test/,$d' | sed '$d' | sed '/^$/d' | tr "\\n" " " | sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d'
```

gives below output - test statistics for the test "Reads 95%"

```
304000,0,8.7931875,7.948696618436826,6907.677974959667,13594.0
```

Next sed command:

```
sed -nr "H;/"Reads 95%"/,/\}/{s/(\})/\1/;T;x;p};/\{/{x;s/.*\n.*//;x;H}" out gives

    {
        "description": "Reads 95%",
        "statistics": [
            304000,
            0,
            8.7931875,
            7.948696618436826,
            6907.677974959667,
            13594.0
        ],
        "test": 101
    },
```

1. pipe result 1 with | sed -e '1,/statistics/d' gives all lines after the line contains "statistics"

   ```
           304000,
           0,
           8.7931875,
           7.948696618436826,
           6907.677974959667,
           13594.0
       ],
       "test": 101
   },
   ```
2. pipe result 2 with | sed -e '/test/,$d' gives lines above the line consists "test"

   ```
           304000,
           0,
           8.7931875,
           7.948696618436826,
           6907.677974959667,
           13594.0
       ],
   ```
3. pipe result 3 with | sed '$d' removes the last line of output 3
               304000,
               0,
               8.7931875,
               7.948696618436826,
               6907.677974959667,
               13594.0
4. pipe result 4 with | tr "\n" " " | sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d' gives

   304000,0,8.7931875,7.948696618436826,6907.677974959667,13594.0

tr "\n" " " replace CRs (or \n) with a space and sed -e 's/[\t ]//g;/^$/d' removes all spaces and tabs

Note: I'm not an expert in this subject area, thus this may not be the most efficient solution

Answer (score 0):

Try sql4json (http://github.com/bheni/sql4json)

installation:

```
sudo pip install sql4json
```

command

```
cat out|sql4json --csv 'SELECT statistics FROM tests WHERE description=="Reads 95%"'
```

output to stdout:

> 304000,0,8.7931875,7.94869661844,6907.67797496,13594.0